# Best approach multi-application networking?

Tags: c#, networking

I have a strange setup as I am doing some experiments.
In this setup, I have 6 applications. Let's call them `A`, `B` and `C` (x4).

`A` connects to `B` and listens on 4 different ports coming from 4 different instances of `C`.

`B` listens on 1 port for a connection from `A` and connects on 4 different ports to the 4 different instances of `C`.

Each instance of `C` listens on 1 port for a connection from `B` and then connects to `A` on another port.

Here is a wonderful art piece to illustrate:

[image]

To manage connections, each listener has the same `NewConnection` handler subscribed to it.

When a connection is received, I add it to a `List<Connection>`.

When receiving messages on `A`, I again use 1 `EventHandler DataReceived` for all connections-in from the different instances of C. Each time the event is raised, the data is added to `ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>`. This queue is shared by all the connections into `A`.

At the moment I only have 4 of `C`, but what if there were more? How can I design this so that `n` `C`'s can connect to `A`?

Also, is it OK that I have just 1 `NewConnection` and 1 `DataReceived` event handlers for all these connections and that all data into A goes into the same `ConcurrentQueue?`

Any suggestions on approach would be appreciated. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do things.

Comment: Sounds like p2p, Kazaa app, etc.. Finding something open source like this on github may help, and not sure if you need different ports for each instance..

Comment: @numbtongue Unfortunately, no open source project is going to do this for me: this is for experimental purposes with rendering research.  Thanks though, I will take a look at p2p.

Comment: What's the actual nature of these applications? (i.e. what exactly are you actually trying to achieve?)   Is there a reason you're using direct connections instead of an MQ or Broker?

Comment: @BenCottrell I am building a cloud-gaming system of sorts, where `A` sends interactions to `B`, which tells each `C` to perform a render task. Each `C` then transmits its result to `A`. It's for research.

Comment: @pookie A bit more specific than that?   I mean, what are the applications?    what kind of traffic is it?     In other words, is there anything stopping you from using a broker or message bus such as RabbitMQ instead of building all these direct connections?

Comment: @BenCottrell I see. The traffic is binary - objects serialised to byte[]. Each "message" contains an image and some properties. I didn't think about RabbitMQ, but I do not know the capabilities of such tools anyway.